# Is there a form to upload files to MEGA(mega.co.nz) from Ubuntu Server(SSH)?

Tags: ssh, client, upload

I was wondering if someones knows how to install a client, like megatools, in Ubuntu Server(SSH) to upload and download files to MEGA(mega.co.nz).

Thanks in advance, Joserex65.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Download mega.nz files from command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1188952/download-mega-nz-files-from-command-line)

Answer (score 9):

You can install megatools like so

```
git clone https://github.com/megous/megatools.git
cd megatools/
sudo apt-get install libtool libglib2.0-dev gobject-introspection libgmp3-dev nettle-dev asciidoc glib-networking#(these are the dependancies I needed, you may need others)
./autogen.sh
make
sudo make install
```

Enjoy!

More robust way which seems to install all the tools:

```
sudo apt-get install libtool libglib2.0-dev gobject-introspection libgmp3-dev nettle-dev asciidoc glib-networking
wget http://megatools.megous.com/builds/megatools-1.9.94.tar.gz
zcat megatools-1.9.94.tar.gz > megatools-1.9.94.tar
tar -xf megatools-1.9.94.tar   
cd megatools-1.9.94/
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

**Edit** To install just the binary on vivid and wily (15.04/15.10), you can just run `sudo apt-get install megatools`. On earlier versions, you can run

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:megous/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install megatools
```

From the [Readme](https://github.com/megous/megatools):

```
Tools
=====

megareg      Register and verify a new mega account
megadf       Show your cloud storage space usage/quota
megals       List all remote files
megamkdir    Create remote directory
megarm       Remove remote file or directory
megamv       Move and rename remote files
megaput      Upload individual files
megaget      Download individual files
megadl       Download file from a "public" Mega link
             (doesn't require login)
megastream   Streaming download of a file
             (can be used to preview videos or music)
megasync     Upload or download a directory tree
megafs       Mount remote filesystem locally.
```

See also http://megatools.megous.com

Comment: Can you perhaps explain what these 'tools' do and why they should be used?  As it currently stands you basically just say "get this random software, build it, and bam it helps", but don't say how it helps in any way.

Comment: @ThomasW. the question mentioned this tool specifically. I've added some details.

Comment: actually he says 'like megatools', which doesn't state they want to use megatools.  To that end, I would suggest editing to sya "YOu can build and use megatools.  Here's the instructions:", to make it a little more complete and kinder towards the end-user.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without installing 729 MB of archives?

Comment: @Maximilian You can run `sudo apt-get install megatools`.

Comment: `E: Unable to locate package megatools`

Comment: @Maximilian It's in vivid and and wily only [right now](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=megatools). You can install it manually by adding https://launchpad.net/~megous/+archive/ubuntu/ppa.

Comment: @Maximilian added instructions to the post

Comment: The OP, Joserex65, said what it was for - quote: "to upload and download files to MEGA(mega.co.nz)"

Answer (score 1):

There is a command line tool provided by the official.

see [MEGAcmd](https://github.com/meganz/MEGAcmd)

Answer (score 0):

try **[Rclone](https://rclone.org/mega/)**

Rclone is a command line program for managing files on cloud storage.

this tool allows us to upload files to mega and not only mega, but more than 40 cloud storage products support rclone including S3 object stores, business & consumer file storage services, as well as standard transfer protocols.

install rclone

```
curl https://rclone.org/install.sh | sudo bash
```

configure with mega account

```
rclone config
```

Upload files to mega

syntax:

```
rclone copy filepath dest:destpath
```

example:

```
rclone copy myfile.txt pausi:backup
```

(this will upload the myfile.txt file to the backup folder in mega)

for download files from mega to local storage.

syntax:

```
rclone copy dest:destpath path
```

example:

```
rclone copy pausi:backup/myfile.txt .
```