# Download mega.nz files from command line

Tags: command-line, server, 18.04, mega

I am running Ubuntu Server 18.04, and I was wondering if it was possible to download mega.nz files from the command-line, e.g. using putty or some other tool?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Megatools allow you to copy individual files as well as entire directory trees to and from the cloud. You can also perform streaming downloads for example to preview videos and audio files, without needing to download the entire file first. Megatools are robust and optimized for fast operation - as fast as Mega servers allow. This is quite fast. Memory requirements and CPU utilization are kept at minimum.

Megatools is provided in Ubuntu by the universe repository. You can install megatools in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu with the following command:

```
sudo apt install megatools
```

Then run `man megatools` to show the available command line tools. The SYNOPSIS section provides a synopsis of the available commands.

Answer (score 11):

As of November/23 the `megatools` repo has been removed, you should look for `megacmd` ([github](https://github.com/meganz/MEGAcmd), from @milahu's answer) instead.

---

As of November/21, Ubuntu 20.04 and megatools 1.10.2, you can use `Megatools` as mentioned in @karel's answer, but `megadl` has [an unfixed issue while dealing with MEGA URLs](https://github.com/megous/megatools/issues/157).

If you need to download a file, the URL will be something like `https://mega.nz/file/<some_id>#<some_other_id>` and needs to be changed into `https://mega.co.nz/#!<some_id>!<some_other_id>` for it to work. Remember to put between single quotes, so:

```
megadl 'https://mega.co.nz/#!<some_id>!<some_other_id>'
```

Folder URLs need to be adapted too, from `https://mega.nz/folder/<some_id>#<some_other_id>` to `https://mega.co.nz/#F!<some_id>!<some_other_id>`, so:

```
megadl 'https://mega.co.nz/#F!<some_id>!<some_other_id>'
```

Comment: `strLink="https://mega.nz/folder/ExdyETia#m0FwgdqrHmfnS4Xakn_rMg/file/R00wWJYZ";megadl "$(echo "$strLink" |sed -r -e 's"mega.nz"mega.co.nz"' -e "s'#'!'g" -e 's"/folder/"/#F!"' -e 's"/file/"!"')"` (the link is for lineageos btw) but I think this link is not downloading (despite accepting the link now) because it is in an encrypted folder see https://github.com/megous/megatools/issues/254. I will try to compile the latest from that github.

Comment: It seems that the bug was resolved now, as far as I can see from the bug tracker.

Comment: The issue was already marked as closed back when I wrote this answer. You can see people as recently as Jan 21 https://github.com/megous/megatools/issues/157#issuecomment-1013698756 claiming the workaround is needed and works as expected.
I haven't touched in this recently, so I can neither confirm nor deny it's been fixed.

Answer (score 2):

[megacmd](https://github.com/meganz/MEGAcmd) works without login

```
mega-get "https://mega.nz/file/bFdkyJhK#xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

have fun building this on debian : P

"proper" distros like [nixos](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/applications/misc/megacmd/default.nix) or [arch](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/megacmd/) have a package for megacmd ...

but you can [use nix on debian](https://www.hillenius.net/post/debian-nix/) : D

```sh
sudo apt install nix nix-setup-systemd
nix-channel --add https://nixos.org/channels/nixpkgs-unstable
nix-channel update
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.nix-profile/bin

nix-env --install megacmd
mega-get ...
```

Comment: this only works if is a public shares; for private ones you'll still have to login

Answer (score -1):

I solved this making a .sh file with 600 lines that look like this:

> megadl 'https://mega.nz/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

You hace to download megatools previously. Give to your .sh file execution permissions (chmod +x fileName) and launch it into your command line (./fileName.sh)